# Формат конца строк как в Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos

Каким образом можно сохранить текст, чтобы формат конца строк был как в OS X ?

Comment: добавлю  \n = \u000A , \r = \u000D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует распространённое заблуждение, что на Mac для переноса строк используется `\r`. На самом же деле этот способ на маках является ископаемым, а на данный момент используется перенос строк как в *nix — `\n`. Windows является исключением, перенос задаётся `\r\n`.

При использовании в C# перенос строк с помощью платформо-зависимых последовательностей возникает при использовании методов вроде `WriteLine`, `AppendLine` и прочих, которые сводятся к добавлению платформо-зависимой последовательности `Environment.NewLine`.

Соответственно, ответ: чтобы использовать свой перенос строк, надо задавать его явно. Например, вместо `StringBuilder.AppendLine("abc")` использовать `StringBuilder.Append("abc\n")`. Некоторые классы, в частности классы для работы с файлами, позволяют переопределять используемую последовательность символов. Например, при создании `StreamWriter` можно указать `new StreamWriter(stream) { NewLine = "\n" }`, тогда вызовы `WriteLine` будут добавлять нужные вам символы. И везде так: указывать переносы явно. Например, для слияния массива строк использовать `string.Join("\n", strings)`.

Если же у вас уже имеется строка с виндовыми переносами, то нужно произвести поиск и замену: `str.Replace("\r\n", "\n")` или даже `str.Replace("\r", "")`. Если вы не знаете, какие переносы используются, то можно использовать регулярные выражения, однако обычно это избыточно, потому что вариантов по сути только два.

Comment: Если код _бежит_ под маком, то по идее должно работать `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @VladD Это да. Но вопрос про использование формата маков на другой платформе, насколько я понимаю, иначе вопрос бы не возник. :)

Answer (score 1):

Под linux есть прекрасная утилита [dos2unix](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/).С помощью нее можно сконвертировать концы строк как в Unix формат, так и обратно dos, или в mac формат

Согласно [этой](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) статье, в OS X символ окончания строки `\n`(LF). Как я понимаю, вы же имеете файл, в котором символ конца строки имеет два символа `\r\n`(CR+LF). 
Соответственно ваша задача сводиться к замене символов `\r\n` на символ `\n`. 
С помощью стандартной функции класса строки [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) вы можете

```
myString = myString.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

После этого получившеюся строку можно записать в файл. Единственное, НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ любые функции записи в файл новой строки.
Предполагаю, что это должно быть так.

Comment: C# указан не просто так. как это сделать кодом?